# How can I iterate all ComboBoxes controls with a loop in C#?

Tags: c#, for-loop, controls

I have some comboBoxes on a winform (for example 10) in C# named: comboBox1, coboBox2 and comboBoxN. How can I access all of them in a for loop like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    comboBox[i].text = "Hello world";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method

```
var comboBoxes =  this.Controls
                  .OfType<ComboBox>()
                  .Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("comboBox"));

foreach(var cmbBox in comboBoxes)
{
    cmbBox.Text = "Hello world";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access to all the combobox in a form that way (assuming `this` is a form):

```
     List<ComboBox> comboBoxList = this.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>();
```

Then you just need to iterate over them

```
     foreach (ComboBox comboBox in comboBoxList)
     {
        comboBox.Text = "Hello world!";
     }
```

Comment: It seems very useful and simple for me but there is a problem with 'this'. How can I use it? Is it form1?

Comment: @UserMat Yes it should be your Form variable, if you named it form1 then it should be form1 ;)

Answer (score 1):

Forms have a [`Controls` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which returns a collection of all controls and which [can be indexed by the name of the control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1865435%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var comboBox = (ComboBox)this.Controls["comboBox" + i.ToString()];
    comboBox.text = "Hello world";
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `this.Controls["comboBox" + i.ToString()]`