# How can I iterate through selected ComboBoxes controls with a loop in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am working in a simple C# form. I have  a total of 20 ComboBoxes . 10 ComboBoxes will contain similar data type and will have very similar name (CB1, CB2, CB3, ... CB10). Each ComboBox was loaded with a list of 5 elements  A,B,C,D,E (by this I meant that I added those values to each of the 10 "CB" ComboBoxes). My intend is that the user can have the ability to select items (one out of A,B,C,D,E) from either 1 combobox, or 2 comboboxes, . . . .,  or all of them (10 comboboxes).

I wish to store the data from the ComboBoxes where an item was selected in a list or array. For that I would like to iterate through the 10 ComboBoxes (the comboboxes  which names are CB1, CB2, CB3, ..., CB10), check if the an item was selected in the combobox, and  store the value selected in the ComboBox into a list (in the code below the list is called symbols). At the end the length of my symbols list (number of items) will depend on how many ComboBoxes the user selected from. Here is the code I am using:

```
List<string> symbols = new List<string>();

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
var my_comboBox = this.Controls["CB" + i.ToString()];
if (null != my_comboBox.SelectedItem) 
{ symbols.add(my_comboBox.Text); }
}
```

when I run the code I get the following error.

**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

**Could anyone please explain what I am doing wrong?** I got the code from another question that was posted and answered,  below is the link to that question. Thanks in advance.

[How can I iterate all ComboBoxes controls with a loop in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699542/how-can-i-iterate-all-comboboxes-controls-with-a-loop-in-c/23699591#23699591)

I also tried the other alternative proposed on the answers to the questions cited. **But it did not work. It does not go through the foreach loop (no error is shown though)**. Here is the code for option 2.

```
 List<string> symbols = new List<string>();

var comboBoxes = this.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>().Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("CB"));

foreach (var cmbBox in comboBoxes)
{
if (null != my_comboBox.SelectedItem) 
{ symbols.add(my_comboBox.Text); }
}
```

Again if anyone can please provide me with ideas to what I am doing wrong that would be very nice. Thanks in advance once more.

The ComboBoxes belong to the form as shown in the picture below. In there the ComboBoxes are called component_CB1,  component_CB2, component_CB3, ..., component_CB10 (I changed the name of the ComboBoxes in the question to CB to make it easier to understand).

[screenshot of my solution explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nutdO.jpg)

Comment: The comboboxes are directly added to the form or they are inside some other container such as group box or panel? Your code would work only if they are directly added to the form.

Comment: Dear @ChetanRanpariya thanks for your help. I am not really sure if the ComboBoxes are directly added into my form "Form1". I uploaded a picture of the solution explorer and the ComboBoxes are there. I believe they are directly added but could you correct.

Comment: From solution explorer I can't figure out if combobox is directly added to the form or added to some container. But I think you are trying to use invalid id to get the comboboxes from controls array. The combobox names start with `component` but you are trying to search with `CB`. You should be doing `this.Controls["component_CB"+i.ToString();`. Also your loop should start with `i =1` coz there is no combobox with name `component_CB0`.

Comment: I see you have tabpage in the form. Can you share the screen capture of form which shows the comboboxes?

Comment: Open your form and then in Visual Studio menu, go to *View* → *Other Windows* → *Document Outline*. You can see if those controls are directly children of form or they are children of another container control. Also as an alternative, to find controls by name, even if they are not direct children of form, you can use: `var combo = this.Controls.Find("component_CB1", true).Cast<ComboBox>().FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Hello, what type of items do you place inside the combo box?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya. I corrected the i from 1 to 10. Thanks for that, although it was not the issue. I also see your point of the name of the comboBox not being in the picture CB but component_CB, I changed the name in the question (here in stack overflow) to CB, in order to make it easier to understand but I was aware of the real name of the comboboxes. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @DarkTemplar the combobox has a list of strings.

Comment: The problem was that the ComboBoxes were not directly added to the form. They were added to a tab on a TabConrtol. Therefore using "this" was not appropriate. The way I corrected was: tabname.Controls["CB" + i.ToString()] for alternative 1 and tabname.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>().Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("CB")) for alternative 2.

Comment: Thanks to @ChetanRanpariya, for pointing me in the right. I used the View → Other Windows → Document Outline in order to see if those controls are directly children of form or they are children of another container control direction.

Comment: Thanks to @RezaAghaei, for pointing me in the right. I used the View → Other Windows → Document Outline in order to see if those controls are directly children of form or they are children of another container control direction.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to everyone who contributed to find the answer to this problem. Please read the comments to identify the contributors.

The answer is that you can iterate through selected ComboBoxes in C#. However for this to work **you need to make sure you know to what  container control your ComboBoxes are added.**

To know to container control your ComboBoxes are added to, *go to View → Other Windows → Document Outline*. You can see if those controls are directly children of the form or they are children of another container control.

If the ComboBoxes are added to your form directly, then here there are two alternatives to iterate through the ComboBoxes:

ALTERNATIVE 1: (ComboBoxes added to the form directly)

```
List<string> symbols = new List<string>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{ //CB is the begining of the name of the comboboxes CB1, CB2, ... CB10
var my_comboBox = this.Controls["CB" + i.ToString()];
if (null != my_comboBox.SelectedItem) 
{ symbols.add(my_comboBox.Text); }
}
```

ALTERNATIVE 2: (ComboBoxes added to the form directly)

```
List<string> symbols = new List<string>();
//CB is the begining of the name of the comboboxes CB1, CB2, ... CB10
var comboBoxes = this.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>().Where(x=>x.Name.StartsWith("CB")); 

foreach (var cmbBox in comboBoxes)
{
if (null != my_comboBox.SelectedItem) 
{ symbols.add(my_comboBox.Text); }
}
```

If the ComboBoxes are added to a different control container (e.g. a tab in a TabControl as in my initial case), **you must specify the control container name rather than "this"**. Here are two alternatives taking as example the ComboBoxes Cb1, CB2, CB3, ..., CB10 that are added to a tab called tab1.

ALTERNATIVE 1: (ComboBoxes added to a tab of a TabControl)

```
List<string> symbols = new List<string>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{//CB is the begining of the name of the comboboxes CB1, CB2, ... CB10
var my_comboBox = tab1.Controls["CB" + i.ToString()];
if (null != my_comboBox.SelectedItem) 
{ symbols.add(my_comboBox.Text); }
}
```

ALTERNATIVE 2: (ComboBoxes added to a tab of a TabControl)

```
List<string> symbols = new List<string>();
//CB is the begining of the name of the comboboxes CB1, CB2, ... CB10
var comboBoxes = tab1.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>().Where(x  
=>x.Name.StartsWith("CB"));

foreach (var cmbBox in comboBoxes)
{
if (null != my_comboBox.SelectedItem) 
{ symbols.add(my_comboBox.Text); }
}
```

Thanks for the help again. I hope this can be useful for others.